# if v/s while: for this code if I'm using while loop it's continuing for infinite, but when used "if(low <high)" its working fine

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, while-loop, quicksort

**Array: 4,1,5,8,2,6,9,7,11,3**

```
public static void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high) {
    System.out.println(low + " " + high);
    while(low < high) {
        int mid = quickPart(arr, low, high);            
        quickSort(arr, low, mid - 1);          
        quickSort(arr, mid + 1, high);
    }
}
```

it's printing: 0 0 then 2 1, then again 0 0 and 2 1 and so on for *S.o.pl(low + " " + high)*

**but for..**

```
public static void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high) {
    System.out.println(low + " " + high);
    if(low < high) {
        int mid = quickPart(arr, low, high);            
        quickSort(arr, low, mid - 1);          
        quickSort(arr, mid + 1, high);
    }
}
```

it's printing: 0 9, 0 1, 0 0, 2 1, 3 9, 3 3, 5 9... it's working fine.

**partitioning code, if it helps..**

```
public static int quickPart(int arr[], int low, int high) {
    int pivot = arr[high];
    int i = low - 1;
    for(int j = low; j < high; j++) {
        if(pivot > arr[j]) {
            i++;
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    int temp = arr[i+1];
    arr[i+1] = arr[high];
    arr[high] = temp;
    System.out.println(i++);
    return i+1;
}
```

For if statement, code will terminate as soon as *low >= high* and for that it is reaching till 9, i.e., 9 > 9 terminate
But for *while + partitioning* algorithm its printing 1 in repetition.
Why is it behaving as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method doesn't change the values of `low` and `high`, so the loop's condition - `(low < high)` will either never be true (and the loop will end immediately) or always be true (and the loop will be infinite).

This is a recursive algorithm, so you don't need a loop. You just need an `if` statement that determines whether the recursion should continue or end.

Comment: So, for that first recursive call which is returning back, while is treating it as "true" and instead of continuing with the recursion, it's looping them. But for if statement it's acting as a simple condition check and continuing with the recursion...(if I'm getting this right)

Answer (score 0):

From [The while and do-while Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

> The while statement evaluates expression, which must return a boolean value. `If the expression evaluates to true, the while statement executes the statement(s) in the while block. The while statement continues testing the expression and executing its block until the expression evaluates to false.`

So in your `while(low < high)` this is alway `true` thats why infinite loop.

Where as [if-then Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

> The if-then statement is the most basic of all the control flow statements. It tells your program to execute a certain section of code only if a particular test evaluates to true.

More importantly unlike loops its execute only one if condtion is ture, thats why its work fine in your case.

for quickSort take a look [QuickSort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/).

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, the while will loop forever since neither low or high are updated, so an if is needed instead, since it only runs once or not at all.

A while is normally used along with a if that only recurses on the smaller partition, then updates low or high and loops back for the larger partition. This limits stack space complexity to O(log(n)), but worst case time complexity is still O(n^2).

```
public static void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high) {
    System.out.println(low + " " + high);
    while(low < high) {
        int mid = quickPart(arr, low, high);
        if((mid-low) <= (high-mid)){
            quickSort(arr, low, mid - 1);
            low = mid+1;
        } else {
            quickSort(arr, mid + 1, high);
            high = mid-1;
        }
    }
}
```